# Radio button click in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: asp.net, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have write a code for radio button click by using XPath but it is not click on radio button during execution of code.

My code is:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(id(),rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_2_ctl01_2)]")).Click();
```

Kindly help how to button select particular radio button and after selection it move to another radio button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser? What version of that Browser? What version of Selenium? Does it find the element but just not click on it? Have you tried other locators?

Comment: Is there anything odd about the way the radiobutton is implemented? Can you post the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `click()` works, but the webdriver can't properly refresh the user interface...

The unique methode i've found to refresh that is to use the `submit()` function on it.

Like :

```
myRadioBtn.click();
myRadioBtn.submit();
```

tell me what's up =)

Answer (score 0):

It might be case that you're checking radio button which is already checked. Hence now, you have radio button unchecked which you don't want(you want radio button to be checked). First check whether radio button is checked. If it's checked, don't click on it(otherwise, it'll result into uncheck of radio button). If it's not checked, then click on it so it will be checked.

```
button = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(id(),rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_2_ctl01_2)]"))

 if (!button.isSelected()){
    button.click();
    assetTrue(button.isSelected)
 }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I am trying to select radio buttons from customization window. If we want to select radio buttons from pop-up window. How to code it for selection.

Comment: Switch to that window driver.switchTo().window("windowHandle") & then perform above actions.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want RadioButton checked?
if yes, try ...Checked=true

```
var radioButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(id(),rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_2_ctl01_2)]"));

radioButton.Checked=true;

(or radioButton.Click())
```